# Network settings won't save DNS servers

Tags: network, dns

This has to be simple: I can't save DNS servers in Network>(Location)>Advanced>DNS

I add the DNS servers

> 1.1.1.1
>
> 1.0.0.1
>
> 2606:4700:4700::1111
>
> 2606:4700:4700::1001

save, and then after a sleep, they revert back to what I assume are my ISPs DNS servers.

Any ideas? Is there a way to lock the panel settings?

Sierra Macbook Pro 1014

Comment: It's overwritten by DHCP.  You should put this in your router so it's consistant

Comment: Ah, that was easy; my mistake. I also have a setting "DNS Relay Configuration:
This controls the DHCP Server to assign public DNS." That's enabled; does that make a difference?

Comment: Not so easy,... DHCP Server allots the IP addresses to computers, while DNS server resolves them. You need DHCP Server if you do not want to manually maintain IP Addresses or you have less IP Addresses than number of machines you have, as dynamic DHCP Server will recycle IP Addresses on machines. DHCP does not dictates DNS.

Comment: Minor detail sometimes forgotten. After changing DNS you must Click OK.

But then `Click Apply` to make it permanent.

Comment: Thanks, I was hitting Apply, rebooting the router, the Macbook, etc. And yes, I don't need to mess with DNS Relay. Should I delete this question, as it is more generic and not really Apple related?

Comment: @Buscar웃 - DHCP does more than just assign IP addresses - it also sends lots of [config options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#DHCP_options) including hostname, DNS, gateway, time servers, tftp servers, etc.  Modern consumer routers utilize [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) that essentially caches DNS entries with the DHCP tables.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch - yes, that does make a difference.  That setting in your router's DHCP server/service tells it to "pass along" the DNS settings it obtained from your ISP and to act as a DNS relay (sends the DNS request upstream).  If you want those particular DNS servers, configure it manually.

Comment: @Allan so what is the purpose me choosing DNS of my liking if it gets overwritten anyway ?

Comment: Create a different location with manual settings.  If you look at the Network Settings page, in the drop down you have the option called "Using DHCP with manual IP address" meaning you set your own address but allow DHCP to write everything else (like DNS).

Comment: @Allan, thanks, turned out to be setting DNS servers in the router; should I delete this question as it is more generic than Apple related?

Comment: Not necessarily....you could answer it and I'll throw you an upvote.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be simple - my DSL router had DNS servers configured, and those were overriding the settings in the Network Control Panel due to DHCP being used. DHCP was grabbing the servers from the router and ISP.

So I changed DNS servers in the router, restarted the router and the Macbook, and then could see the 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1 servers in the Advanced>TCP settings; they were grayed out since they were set in the router.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!